# JPA match subset of elements in a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

in my database I have two tables: Person and Language. The two tables are mapped in Hibernate in a many-to-many relationship with each person speaking multiple languages.

Now I want to write a method which takes a list of languages and returns a list of people speaking ALL (logical AND) of those languages. I tried to build a criteria like:

```
Restrictions.in("languages", languagesList);
```

but this resulted back in a list of people speaking ANY (logical OR) of those languages.

I looked online and I found that there are some tricks using conjunctions and NOT EXISTS but they looked more like hacks so I wanted to check if there's a cleaner approach to achieve this.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the understanding of the underlying relational model and not with Hibernate. The [`Restrictions.in`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#in-java.lang.String-java.util.Collection-) builder maps to the SQL `IN` operator so your result is not unexpected at all.

In SQL this problem is interesting, too. A possible approach is this ([full SQL source](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/9c55ff23cc9f7e3b3f059b28a4a79c4b)):

```sql
select u.user_name, count(l.language_name)
  from user u
  join user_language ul on u.user_name = ul.user_name
  join language l on l.language_name = ul.language_name
 where l.language_name in ('spanish', 'italian')
 group by u.user_name
 having count(l.language_name) = 2
```

The parameters of the query are:

- the array of languages (`'spanish', 'italian'`)
- the length of the array (`2`)

Unfortunately I don't have Hibernate at hand right now, but I think you'd be better off using HQL rather than the Criteria API for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try a JPQL query that first selects all the persons that speak one language and then selects from that list all the people that also speak the other language.

```
List<Person> ps = em.createQuery("select distinct p from Person p join p.languages l where l.languageName = 'english' "
+ " and p.id in (select distinct p.id from Person p join p.languages l where l.languageName = 'spanish' )", Person.class).getResultList();
```

Should work.